# Pegar apenas o ano de uma coluna no MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma query que tem uma condição, que verifica se o registro é maior ou igual a data de hoje.

Ele esta dessa forma:

```
WHERE t1.bidpack_buy_date => NOW()
```

Bom, ai ele vai verificar se o valor da coluna `bidpack_buy_date` é maior ou igual a data e hora atual.

Na coluna `bidpack_buy_date` ele fica gravado dessa forma:

**2018-01-10 09:00:00**

Eu preciso que nessa condição, ele verifique apenas o dia, mês e ano. Ou seja, será válido apenas se for igual a data de hoje ou depois, a hora deve ser considerada.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se quiser checar individual, pode usar

`WHERE YEAR(bidpack_buy_date) => YEAR(NOW())`

ou

`WHERE MONTH(bidpack_buy_date) => MONTH(NOW())`

Para checar a data sem a hora, então:

`WHERE DATE(bidpack_buy_date) => DATE(NOW())`

Da mesma forma, para checar apenas a hora:

`WHERE TIME(bidpack_buy_date) => TIME(NOW())`

Comment: Mas aia ele vai ficar separado,tem como verificar o ano, mes e dia na mesma condição?

Comment: Editei a resposta com essa informação também, Wendler! :)

Comment: Pode me dizer se fiz certo, e se a query ta correta?

Comment: `DELETE t1 FROM bid_account t1 INNER JOIN bid_account t2 WHERE t1.id > t2.id AND t1.bidding_price = t2.bidding_price AND t1.auction_id = '" . $obj->auction_id . "' AND t1.bidding_type = 's' AND t1.bid_flag = 'd' AND DATE(t1.bidpack_buy_date) => DATE(NOW())`

Comment: Creio que seja assim mesmo, Wendler! Faz uma cópia dessa tabela e faz um teste pra não afetar se estiver em produção rs

Comment: Deu certo, Wendler?

Comment: Deu sim @Cleber Griff, muito obrigado! =)

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que a pergunta já foi respondida mas outra forma de fazer é usando a função [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp):

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE DATE_FORMAT($data, "%Y%m%d") > DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%Y%m%d");
```

Obs.: No link tem as opções para formatação da string

Se possui uma diferença de performance eu não sei dizer, mas não deve ser exorbitante